# How to loop over different Sequelize queries using transactions

Tags: node.js, promise, sequelize.js

Currently, I am trying to do an iteration over an array of objects which need to be inserted depending on the number of items in the array (from request.body).

> **Expected behavior:**
>
> I thought that the for loop would result in different sequelize SQL queries which will be inserted into the database one after the other.

--

> **Actual behavior:**
>
> The actual behavior is that only the last item in the array is inserted into the database and the first one is overwritten and not being inserted into the database.

--

> **My question:**
>
> How to change this existing logic to be able to insert multiple records into the database while using transactions / sequelize SQL queries?

The data I send to the API request is:

```
[{
  "venue_id": 5,
  "event_id": 13,
  "table_id": 4,
  "date_in": "2017-11-30",
  "date_out": "2017-12-31",
  "check_in": "2017-12-31T17:04:42.333Z",
  "check_out": "2017-12-31T17:05:42.333Z"
},
{
  "venue_id": 6,
  "event_id": 18,
  "table_id": 6,
  "date_in": "2017-11-30",
  "date_out": "2017-12-31",
  "check_in": "2017-12-31T17:04:42.333Z",
  "check_out": "2017-12-31T17:05:42.333Z"
}]
```

**The API call logic can be found below. This API request basically does the following things:**

> 1. Starts a SQL transaction in order to either commit or rollback when something goes wrong.
> 2. Searches for a venueId and CustomerId and TableId. (in case someone tries to insert some non-existing ids)
> 3. Calculates the price of the tables together
> 4. Creates a reservation
> 5. Commits the transaction and returns response.

```
router.post(
  "/api/v1/reservations",
  [passport.authenticate("jwt", { session: false }), isCustomer],
  (request, response) => {

    return models.sequelize.transaction().then(t => {


      // I was trying to do this by using a for loop but it doesn't seem to work.

      for (var i = 0; i < request.body.length; i++) {

        return models.Venue.findById(request.body[i].venue_id)
          .then(venue => {
            return models.Customer.findById(request.customer.id);
          })
          .then(customer => {
            return models.Table.findAllById(request.body[i].table_id);
          })
          .then(tables => {
            var price = 0;

            for (var i = 0; i < tables.length; i++) {
              price = price + tables[i].price;
            }

            return models.Reservation.createReservation(
              request.body[i],
              price,
              request.customer.id
            ).then(reservation => {
              return reservation.addTables(tables).then(() => {
                if (request.body.length - 1 === i) {
                  t.commit().then(() => {
                    return response.status(200).send(reservation);
                  });
                }
              });
            });
          })
          .catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
            t.rollback().then(() => {
              return response.status(error.status_code).send(error.message);
            });
          });
      }
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You have made your code look so complex and you are reaching to **[callback hell](http://callbackhell.com/)** situation , I would suggest to use **[aysnc await](https://hackernoon.com/6-reasons-why-javascripts-async-await-blows-promises-away-tutorial-c7ec10518dd9)** :

Here I have tried to achieve almost error less code from yours , but still your code looks to complicated , please try to solve if have any errors. But this is the way you can achieve you are expecting :

```
router.post(
"/api/v1/reservations", [passport.authenticate("jwt", {
    session: false
}), isCustomer],
(request, response) => {

    return models.sequelize.transaction().then(async (t) => { // <--- ASYNC

        // I was trying to do this by using a for loop but it doesn't seem to work.

        for (var i = 0; i < request.body.length; i++) {

            try{
                let venue = await models.Venue.findById(request.body[i].venue_id) // <--- AWAIT
                let customer = await models.Customer.findById(request.customer.id); // <--- AWAIT
                let tables = await models.Table.findAllById(request.body[i].table_id); // <--- AWAIT
                let price = 0;

                for (var i = 0; i < tables.length; i++) {
                    price = price + tables[i].price;
                }

                let reservation = await models.Reservation.createReservation(
                    request.body[i],
                    price,
                    request.customer.id
                ); // <--- AWAIT   
                await reservation.addTables(tables); // <--- AWAIT
                if (request.body.length - 1 === i) {
                    await t.commit();
                    // return response.status(200).send(reservation); 
                }
            } catch (err) {
                await t.rollback();
                return response.status(error.status_code).send(error.message);
            }
        }

    });
}
```

> Hope this will help you to get what you want :)

---

> The actual behavior is that only the last item in the array is
>   inserted into the database and the first one is overwritten and not
>   being inserted into the database.
>
> **Reason** : Is async behaviour , look in your first for loop , it will
>   get executed no matter your inner code executed or not , so it will
>   loop through all the request.body first and then your inner code will
>   start execute , this is called **[event loop](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8aGhZQkoFbQ)**

Comment: Cheers bud, I already managed to fix it. I will update my answer soon!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a for loop, I have used a foreach loop. After some small adjustments it seems to work.